# CSS using svg as background, external pattern doesn't load

Tags: css, design-patterns, svg, load

If I put the SVG like an object it works fine (only console errors on chrome about mime types etc): [www.bunquer.com](http://www.bunquer.com)

I want to put this like a background, but in that case the **pattern inside the mountains doesn't loads why?**
http://bunquer.com/tests/svg/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When SVG is used as an image the SVG file must be self-contained for privacy reasons. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=628747 for more details and reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but if is for privacy reasons, **why does it works like an object?**
I have try to do it with a embedded image (throug inkscape) and despite the weight svg+png8 = 90 K VS svg_embedded 340K it doesn't show at all